# 'SET' must be a type

Tags: sql, oracle

I created the following types :

```
CREATE TYPE Adress AS Object (Street varchar2(50), PostalC number, Ville varchar2(50));
CREATE TYPE PhoneNumber;
```

A person can have a set of PhoneNumbers, when I try to create the Type Person :

```
CREATE TYPE Person AS Object (FirstName varchar2(50), LastName varchar2(50), Adr Adress, Mobile SET(PhoneNumber));
```

I get the following error :

> Errors: TYPE PERSON Line/Col: 0/0 PL/SQL: Compilation unit analysis
> terminated Line/Col: 1/90 PLS-00488: 'SET' must be a type

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using?

Comment: @Dai I am working on Oracle Live SQL.

Comment: seems you're confused with `MySQL` which has such a syntax for table creation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want an array of phone numbers for each person, define the phone number type as a nested table:

```
create or replace type address as object (
  street varchar2(50), postalc number, ville varchar2(50)
);
/

create or replace type phonenumber as table of varchar2(20);
/

create or replace type person as object (
  firstname varchar2(50), lastname varchar2(50), 
  adr address, mobile phonenumber
);
```